# How can all subsets in be "built up" from these particular subsets?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal F$ be a sigma-algebra, and write $|\mathcal F|$ for the total number of subsets in $\mathcal F$.

Prove that if $|\mathcal F|<\infty$, then $|\mathcal F|=2^m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

Hint: Consider those non-empty subsets in $\mathcal F$ which do not contain any other non-empty set in $\mathcal F$.

My question: How can all subsets in  be "built up" from these particular subsets?

Comment: Please help answer  ......

Answer (score 1):

Expansion of the hint (these sets form a *partition* of the whole space)

---

Let $X$ denote the whole space, let $x\in X$ and let $A_{x}=\bigcap\left\{ A\in\mathcal{F}\mid x\in A\right\} $.

Observe that $x\in A_{x}$ and also $A_{x}\in\mathcal{F}$ since $\mathcal{F}$
is finite.

Remark: the finiteness of $\mathcal F$ is not only sufficient for this but (unfortunately) also necessary, as commented by Bungo.

Then for $B\in\mathcal{F}$ the assumption that $\varnothing\neq B\subseteq A_{x}$
leads to the conclusion that $B=A_{x}$ (do you see how?).

So $A_{x}$ can be recognized as one of the sets mentioned in the
hint.

That means that for every $x\in X$ we can find such a set that contains $x$.

Let $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ denote the collection of such
sets and let it have $m$ elements.

Above it has been shown that $X$ is covered by $\mathcal P$. Further the elements of $\mathcal P$ are not empty and it is not difficult to prove that $\mathcal P$ is actually a (finite) partition of $X$.

Now prove that every $B\in\mathcal{F}$ can be written as a union
of elements of $\mathcal{P}$.

What can you conclude about the cardinality of $\mathcal F$ on base of this?

I hope this is enough for you.

---

**addendum**:

If $x\notin B$ then $x\in B^{\complement}\in\mathcal{F}$ and the
definition of $A_{x}$ tells us that $A_{x}\subseteq B^{\complement}$.

But then $B\subseteq A_{x}\subseteq B^{\complement}$ and $B\subseteq B^{\complement}$ implies that $B=\varnothing$.

So we conclude that $x\in B$.

Then the definition of $A_{x}$ tells
us that $A_{x}\subseteq B$.

Next to that we have $B\subseteq A_{x}$
so the conclusion $B=A_{x}$ is justified.

Comment: excuse me . why B=A_x

Comment: I have added something to make that clear.

Comment: No, but you really don't need that for doing mathematics. Glad to help and good luck.

Comment: can you help in problem .                                                                                                                   Let (omega,F, P) be the uniform distribution on omega ={1, 2, 3}, Give an example of a sequence A1 , A2 , A3, • • • € F such that                                                                      P( lim inf An) < lim inf P(An) < lim sup P(An) < P( lim sup An) ,
  such that all three inequalities are strict.

Comment: (+1) Simple way to see that $\mathcal P$ is a partition: suppose $A,B \in \mathcal P$ and $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. Then since $A\cap B$ is a subset of both $A$ and $B$, which are sets of the type described in the hint, this forces $A \cap B = A$ and $A \cap B = B$, whence $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, so $A=B$.

Comment: Thought I would also mention that the assumption that $|\mathcal F| < \infty$ is necessary in order to conclude that $A_x \in \mathcal F$. Any infinite sigma algebra is uncountable, and sigma algebras are only guaranteed to be closed under countable intersections.

Comment: @mahak E.g. $\{1\},\{1,2\},\{3\},\{1\},\{1,2\},\{3\},\{1\},\dots$ et cetera (i.e. repetition). Then $\liminf A_n=\varnothing$ and $\limsup A_n=\{1,2,3\}$ and $\liminf P(A_n)$ and $\limsup P(A_n)$ are easy to find. Actually it is not according to the rules here to ask completely different questions in comments. So this is the last time, okay? (I could not resist). Also if this answer is enough for your original question then there is a possibility for you to accept it.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you. I added a remark on the necessity of the finiteness of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: please help in lim supP(An) and lim infP(An)

Comment: @mahak If $(A_n)_n$ is the sequence proposed in my former comment then $(P(A_n))$ is the sequence $\frac13,\frac23,\frac13,\frac13,\frac23,\frac13,\frac13,\dots$. Can you find the $\liminf P(A_n)$ and $\limsup P(A_n)$ on base of this?

Comment: lim supP(An)={1/3,2/3,1/3}                                          lim infP(An)={0}? but  P(lim sup An) and P(lim inf An)= ?

Comment: Working with $(P(A_n))_n$ you are not dealing with a sequence of sets but with a sequence of **real numbers**. If $(r_n)_n$ is a sequence of real numbers with $r_1=\frac13$, $r_2=\frac23$ et cetera (as in my former comment) then e.g. $\liminf r_n=\frac13$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_sequences).

Comment: in the inequalities?

Comment: We have $P(\liminf A_n)=P(\varnothing)=0$ and $P(\limsup A_n)=P(\{1,2,3\}=1$. Next to that $\liminf P(A_n)=\frac13$ and $\limsup P(A_n)=\frac23$. Now  $$0<\frac13<\frac23<1$$ verifies that: $$P(\liminf A_n)<\liminf P(A_n)<\limsup P(A_n)<P(\limsup A_n)$$